# Should sub-domain be preferred short or long?

Tags: subdomain

I want to make a sub-domain but I am not sure if having a shorter sub-domain will benefit in SEO or longer sub-domain will? For example - components-of-computer.blog.com or comp.blog.com

Answer (score 1):

Actually, neither.

Your domain name and sub-domain name should have the following criteria at least:

- Easy and natural to remember.
- Retains "top of mind" recall. (comes to mind easily and first)
- Has semantic value. (uses whole words that signal the topic)
- Uses whole terms that mean something to a user.
- Convenient to type.

While there is a lot of discussion whether a sub-domain or a sub-directory is preferred, topic is always an issue. Generally speaking, sub-directories are always better if on topic. However, if the topic is not fully complementary to the parent domain, then a sub-domain could be the answer if not another domain entirely.

The reason why I say this is two fold: one, the semantic value of the terms between the sub-domain and parent domain should make sense and send signals as to what the topic is about. For example, microcars.reallysmallcars.com or reallysmallcars.com/microcars. Since a microcar is a really small car, it should be a sub-directory, however, if you chose for it to be a sub-domain, then the semantic value of the sub-directory should explain the topic. There is no question what content can be found on microcars.reallysmallcars.com.

In your example, `comp` of comp.blog.com means nothing semantically. Comp is not a word and would mean absolutely nothing to a search engine or human. As well, components-of-computer.blog.com is awkward. It would be difficult to remember and type. However, components.computerblog.com or computerblog.com/components would be a significant improvement.

Comment: In other words "a short as possible while still having meaning"

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Bingo! That would be the TL;DR version!!